# OpenCV Houghline function create unlimited lines

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am still very new to OpenCV and recently came across the Houghline function. I am using OpenCV 3.2 with Visual Studio 2015. I tried the sample code for HoughlineP without success. The code compiles fine but it runs endless, and sometimes when I push "stop debugging" it popup "Unhandled exception at.........Access violation reading location ..." errors. When I debugged it, it seems cause by the HoughlinsP function (the Canny and cvtColor works good). The lines size=1152921504603840390 (a ridiculous huge number) after the HoughlinesP function. Could you please advice? Thank you.

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{
Mat src, dst, color_dst;
src = imread("C:\\\Temp\\\img.jpg");
if (src.empty())
    return -1;
Canny(src, dst, 50, 200, 3);
cvtColor(dst, color_dst, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

vector<Vec4i> lines;
HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 80, 30, 10);
for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
{
    line(color_dst, Point(lines[i][0], lines[i][1]),
        Point(lines[i][2], lines[i][3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, 8);
}

namedWindow("Source", 1);
imshow("Source", src);
namedWindow("Detected Lines", 1);
imshow("Detected Lines", color_dst);
waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your attention. It is solved by taking opencv_world320.lib out of the debug linker input.