# OpenCV 3.2.0 HoughLinesP returns out of bounds lines (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, hough-transform

I've been trying to detect some lines (on edges) in live webcam images, so I tried to do canny edge detection followed by hough transform using C++ version of OpenCV 3.2.0.

There shouldn't be any issues since using HoughLinesP looks straightforward, but it seems that I can't make it work.

The problem is that the vector output that is supposed to contain detected lines, is filled with a **couple million of garbage results**!

This is how I call HoughLinesP:

```
vector<Vec4i> lines;
HoughLinesP(cannyd, lines, 1, CV_PI/180.0, 100, 100, 10);
```

and then try to output the detected lines like:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    Vec4i l = lines[i];
    printf("line: %d %d %d %d\n", l[0], l[1], l[2], l[3]);
}
```

But I get about 3-4 million lines in return (size of *lines* vector after detection)! Most of which are (0, 0, 0, 0). Some other detected lines look like this:

```
line: 0 0 1161992204 -1946150912
line: 2000556868 1404 17730960 17730984
line: 17730968 17447528 2 2000558912
line: 0 0 0 0
line: 1163630597 -2147477248 0 17736008
line: 0 0 32 17736008
line: 0 1684957559 30575 0
line: 0 0 1163171842 -2147476992
```

which is totally strange as the input image is 640*480 in size, and these numbers are not nearly correct.

Appreciate your help

Edit: Posting more code (as per @Alexander's suggestion)

```
VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);
cap >> image;
cvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
blur(gray, gray, Size(3, 3));
Canny(gray, cannyd, 50, 150, 3);
// This is where above-mentioned Hough codes run
```

Comment: What does `cannyd` look like? Edit: Can you post all of your current code?

Comment: Thanks for answering @Alexander, but posting all my code here will certainly look messy. `cannyd` is a 640*480 Mat, that comes straight out of canny edge detector, so the background is black, and the detected edges are white.

Comment: Can you at least post the relevant pieces which make it's way into your Hough Transform? Specifically following `cannyd` back to `imread()`. I would hazard to guess a memory issue.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds more code added, thanks for your time

Comment: Presumably you just initialize `cannyd` with `Mat cannyd;`?

Comment: "but posting all my code here will certainly look messy" -- of course it would. That's why you're supposed to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds of course, that and `image` and `gray`.

Comment: [This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645923/opencv-houghline-function-create-unlimited-lines) has a posted (not accepted) answer, not sure if it will help. Let us know.

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderReynolds, I was unable to solve the issue despite the link you posted seeming related to my issue.
But I tried building opencv3.0.0 and the problem went away and I'm happy with it for now.
Thanks again for your time.