# OpenCV Hough Line Transform gives non-existent horizontal lines

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I first extract edges from a binary image using canny detector. The result is perfect, but then I used the hough transform to vectorize those edges. However, the lines I got are erroneous that tons of non-existent horizontal lines just pop out of nowhere.

Edges
[image: edges]

Hough lines
[image: lines]

100 votes
[image]

Code and parameters I used

```
    // detect edges.
    cv::Mat1b edges(bw.size());
    cv::Canny(bw, edges, 40, 120);

    // detect lines.
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
    cv::HoughLinesP(edges, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 0);

    // minimum 100 votes version.
    cv::HoughLinesP(edges, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100);

    cv::Mat1b tmp(edges.size());
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < lines.size(); i ++) {
            cv::Vec4i const& line = lines[i];
            cv::line(tmp, cv::Point(line[0], line[1]), cv::Point(line[2], line[3]), cv::Scalar(255));
    }
```

Comment: Why is your threshold 0? One way you can think about a Hough transform is that it fills your image with lines, and then for every white pixel in your image laying on that line, give that line +1 to it's score. With the `threshold` you're asking "how many points does a line have to touch for me to count it as a line?" So if your threshold is 0 that means...every possible line from Hough is in your image. Instead try 50 or 100 or something like that. This isn't actually how Hough transform works but it's pretty close.

Comment: I see. It should call the number of votes then. After I set the threshold to 100, 300 and 500, the horizontal lines are fixed, but the good lines are gone. I'll edit the post to include these images.

Comment: Oh. Nope, you're having a different weird issue. There was a very similar question recently that had *millions* of lines in `lines`. Also the values in each `line` were completely bizarre, massive numbers. Do you as well? It looks to be a really strange bug. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661140/opencv-3-2-0-houghlinesp-returns-out-of-bounds-lines-c). Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43645923/opencv-houghline-function-create-unlimited-lines) has a posted answer, not sure if it will help.

Comment: Yes, I am using OpenCV 3.2 as well. When I set the threshold to 100 votes, I got about 500 lines in that simple edge map, but the code doesn't crash. The lines I guess are fine. It's just that they are horizontal. I am not sure if this would be considered a bug. Since the line in the edge map is 2 pixels wide, it's possible to get some horizontal lines with 0 threshold. Now, It seems strange to me that there are still horizontal lines after thresholding to 100 votes. Let me try the example and see if I can replicate that problem.

Comment: Yeah, no---aside from the threshold, your code looks fine. With a little modification to your code (mostly to just resize your image) I was easily able to detect [basically the whole outline fine](http://imgur.com/a/QFEbt).

Comment: I finally figured it out. The problem was I used cv::Mat1b tmp(edges.size()); as the output target. It seems cv::line isn't able to draw binary image. It probably overflowed the image boundary causing those erroneous pixels. When I switched it to cv::Mat1i tmp(edges.size()); things are perfectly fine. Thanks though.

Comment: Right on! Post an answer to your question then, in case others stumble upon this.

Answer (score 1):

After some struggling, I found out that it wasn't the problem with the hough transform. The problem was I used cv::Mat1b tmp(edges.size()); as the output target. It seems cv::line isn't able to draw binary image. It probably overflowed the image boundary causing those erroneous pixels. When I switched it to cv::Mat1i tmp(edges.size()); things are perfectly fine.

The fixed code

```
    // detect edges.
    cv::Mat1b edges(bw.size());
    cv::Canny(bw, edges, 40, 120);

    // detect lines.
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
    cv::HoughLinesP(edges, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 40, 100, 200);

    cv::Mat1i tmp(edges.size());
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < lines.size(); i ++) {
            cv::Vec4i const& line = lines[i];
            cv::line(tmp, cv::Point(line[0], line[1]), cv::Point(line[2], line[3]), cv::Scalar(255));
    }

    cv::imwrite("tmp.png", tmp);
```

Result:
[image]